# Storing user access on objects

Tags: authorization

I have a web app that has different types of object: `Car`, `Client`, `Lead`. Each record has a user owner and a user can do according to its permissions action only on its own records. Database is MySQL.

I need to add to the  system a feature where a user can share a specific record to a user(or a group of users)- probably with access level (read,write,full). How can I store these permissions in order to have an efficient system of filtering that when they are queried. For example, in this moment, the only condition was smth like  `owner_id=user->id`.

One way would be to have a table with: record_id, record_type, share_user_id, access_level. For a record data will be recalculated when ever "share settings" are changed.

My fear is that having a lot of objects, this table would grow in size (over 10K of objects, over 100 users). Is there any other approach?

Comment: Any halfway decent database should be able to handle way more than 10K rows. Have you experienced an actual performance problem?

Comment: I have not implemented yet. I did not have any problems with large tables. The problem is that this a solution I came up with, and I am not sure if this is a proper way to do it.